# copy allocated char array to "normal" char array

Tags: c, malloc, strcpy

Please, tell me, what is the correct way of copying allocated char array to "normal" char array?
I have attempted to do the following, but it fails :

```
char * buf = (char *) malloc (BUFSIZ * sizeof(char));
// filling up the allocated array with stuff...
char temp[BUFSIZ];
strcpy(temp, buf); // strcpy doesn't work
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Also note that by the C standards, a char is equal to one byte, so the `* sizeof(char)` is not necessary.

Comment: use `memcpy`, since you don't have to analyze your buffer and search for 0-terminator

Comment: You should provide more info on what makes you think that strcpy did not work (e.g. a printf that didn't show what you expected, etc.)

Comment: C or C++? If you're really in C++, all this messing with memory and pointers is discouraged.

Comment: You've tagged this "C++", but in C++ you'd use `std::string`, right?

Comment: it should have worked. can you also post the code which fills buf?

Comment: @AdityaNaidu: Only if the string is null-terminated.

Comment: Bods, _nowhere_ in the question is the term "string" used. This could just be a regular `char` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you should not cast the return value of `malloc` (in C anyway) since it can hide errors.

Secondly, you *never* need to multiply by `sizeof(char)` since it's always guaranteed to be one - doing so clogs up your code.

And, as to the actual question, you can use:

```
memcpy (temp, buff, BUFFSZ);
```

to copy the entire character array.

I'm assuming that's what you want because you make *no* mention of handling C "strings", only a character array.

If indeed you *are* handling C strings, `strcpy` will work fine in this case, provided:

- you have room at the end of the buffer for the terminating zero-byte; and
- you've actually *put* the zero-byte in there.

For example, this little snippet works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    // Two buffers.

    char buff1[4];
    char *buff2 = malloc (4);
    if (buff2 == NULL) {
        puts ("No memory!");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate first buffer.

    buff2[0] = 'p';
    buff2[1] = 'a';
    buff2[2] = 'x';
    buff2[3] = '\0';

    // Transfer and print.

    strcpy (buff1, buff2);
    puts (buff1);

    // Free and exit.

    free (buff2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Casting the return value of `malloc` is necessary in C++, however.

Comment: Despite the C++ tag, this is almost certainly a C question. You would rarely have a need to use malloc or C-style strings in C++.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is `strncpy()`, which copies up to a certain number of bytes from a string.

```
strncpy(temp, buf, BUFSIZ - 1);
temp[BUFSIZ - 1] = '\0'; // null terminate the string
```

If that too fails, possibly just use `memcpy()`

```
memcpy(tmp, buf, BUFSIZ - 1);
temp[BUFSIZ - 1] = '\0'; // null terminate the string
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` works with zero-terminated strings, not arbitrary lumps of memory.

If you have filled it with a terminated string, then `strcpy` should work; if it doesn't, please give more information about how it "doesn't work".

If you don't want a terminated string, then use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(temp, buf, BUFSIZ);
```

Note that there's no need to multiply by `sizeof(char)`, since that is 1 by definition.

If you're actually writing C++, then you probably want to use `std::vector` or `std::string` rather than messing around with raw memory.

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` is a function that copy a string.

A string is a sequence of character terminated by and including the null character.

```
 char *buf = malloc(BUFSIZ);
```

This `malloc` call allocates an array BUFSIZ of `char` but this is not a string.
To copy an array use the memcpy function:

```
memcpy(temp, buf, BUFSIZ);
```

If your array holds a string (a sequence of characters terminated by a null character), you can then use `strcpy` to copy it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a terminating `NUL` character in your `buf`. You should make sure to do `buf[last_actually_used_char+1] = '\0';`. This means `buf` will have to be one character larger than the data you wish to store.

This is necessary because `strcpy` finds the length of the information to be copied by searching for a terminating `NUL`.

I strongly encourage the use of the safer `strncpy`, or if you just want to copy *data* (no `'\0'` necessary) the faster and safer `memcpy`.